# fullcalendar week view - show resources instead of hours

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using **fullcalendar** and **scheduler** in my `angular2` application.

As a "directive" I use **primeng** approach for wrapping scheduler [from here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/components/schedule/schedule.ts).

In **day view** I can display **Resources** vertically and **hours** horizontally  - this is OK.
[image: DayView]

When I switch to **weekView** I need to show the **Resources** in the same way (vertically) and **week days** (horizontally). 
Actually I have **day hour** (vertically) and **week days** (horizontally).

[image]
Can someone guide me how to realize that please. (For WeekView Show Resources vertically and weekDays horizontally).

### Thanks.

Code snippets:

**Component:**

```
export class SchedulerComponent implements OnInit {

    events: any;
    resources: any;
    header: any;

    resourceText: string;
    eventBgColor: string;

    height: number;
    contentHeight: number;
    resourceAreaWidth: number; 
    eventStartEditable: boolean;
    eventDurationEditable: boolean;
    dragRevertDuration: boolean;
    defaultView: string;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.initResources();
        this.initEvents();
        this.initOptions();
    }

    initOptions() {
        this.header = {
            left: 'today prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'timelineDay,agendaWeek,month'                
        };

        this.resourceText = 'Rooms';
        this.resourceAreaWidth = 250;

        this.eventBgColor = 'DeepSkyBlue';

        this.height = 25 * this.resources.length;
        this.contentHeight = 25 * this.resources.length + 290;
        this.eventStartEditable = true;
        this.eventDurationEditable = true;
        this.dragRevertDuration = false;
        this.defaultView = "timelineDay";
    }
}
```

Html Template:

```
<schedule [header]="header"
           [resources]="resources"
           [events]="events"
           [resourceLabelText]="resourceText"
           [eventBackgroundColor]="eventBgColor"

           [contentHeight]="contentHeight"
           [resourceAreaWidth]="resourceAreaWidth"
           [eventStartEditable]="eventStartEditable"
           [eventDurationEditable]="eventDurationEditable"
           [dragRevertDuration]="dragRevertDuration"
           [defaultView]="defaultView"

          >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to customize the view. (I am not sure it is the best way. You are welcome to suggest other approaches.)

Bellow is my solution:
in `initOptions` I configure the `header` in this way:

```
this.header = {
            left: 'today prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'timelineDay,timelineWeek,month'                
        };
```

***Attention***: instead of **agendaWeek** i used **timelineWeek**.

Also, this was not enough for my needs. 
It was necessary to make the **slotDuration** equal with 24hours.

in my component I've added the field `slotDuration`, and i initialized it in `initOptions` method.

```
/*.properties...*/
slotDuration: string;

/*.initOptions..*/
this.slotDuration = '24:00:00';
```

I added this line to my html template: `[slotDuration]="slotDuration"`

The result [image]

***Note:*** by using the **slotDuration** equal with 24 hours will affect **DayView**. Actually I will investigate how to change the **slotDuration** on `ViewSwitch` event in order to make it equal with 1hour for **DayView** and 24Hours for **WeekView**.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an informational reply, I achieved the same view by adding the following in to my calendar setup code :

```
        header: {
            left: 'today prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'timelineMyWeek,timelineMonth'
        },
        defaultView: 'timelineMyWeek',
        views: {
            timelineMyWeek: {
                type: 'timelineWeek',
                slotDuration: '24:00:00'
            },
        },
```

the benefit being that this has no change effect on other views